# How to return "addEventListener()" from another function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my code shorter and more optimized, and want to make it look clearer.

So far I did this :

```js
function id(a) {
  return document.getElementById(a);
}

function cl(a) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(a);
}

function tg(a) {
  return document.getElementsByTagName(a);
}

function qs(a) {
  return document.querySelector(a);
}

function qa(a) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(a);
}
```

Now I have the possibility to call `qs("#myElement")`. Now I want to attach a event to the specified element just like `qs("#myElement").addEventListener("click", callBack)`. It works great for me. But when I try to make this :

```js
function ev(e, call) {
  return addEventListener(e, callback);
}
```

And then try to call `qs("#init-scrap").ev("click", someFunction)` then it pops up the following error :

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: qs(...).ev is not a function.`. I don't know what is the problem, do I have to try method chaining ? or any other way I can resolve this problem.

Note : I don't want to use any libraries or frameworks liek Jquery etc.

Comment: *"I am trying to make my code shorter and more optimized, and want to make it look clearer"* these are three different things, wich usually contradict ech other. Short code is often not optimized and not necessarily clear or easy to read. readable code is not necessarily short nor optimized. And optimized code is almost never short or readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use syntax `qs("#init-scrap").ev("click", someFunction)`, you need to wrap object returned by `querySelector` into another object that has `ev` function.

```
class jQueryLite {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  ev(e, callback) {
    this.el.addEventListener(e, callback);
    return this;
  }
}

qs(a) {
  return new jQueryLite(document.querySelector(a));
}
```

It's called Fluent interface, if you wish to look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the element/nodelist in as the first argument and attached the listener to it.

```
function ev(el, e, call) {
  return el.addEventListener(e, callback);
}
```

As an alternative, but not something I would recommend, you could add `ev` as a new `Node` prototype function:

```js
function qs(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

if (!Node.prototype.ev) {
  Node.prototype.ev = function(e, cb) {
    return this.addEventListener(e, cb);
  };
}

qs('button').ev('click', handleClick);

let count = 0;

function handleClick() {
  console.log(count++);
}
```

```html
<button>Count+=1</button>
```

**Note** I've only tested this with `document.querySelector`. You might have to alter the code to work with `document.querySelectorAll` etc as they don't return single elements.

Comment: But how can I bind it to the already got element through `ps("#element")` ?

Comment: See amended answer @NadeemAhmad.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `ev` method. It should be

```
const ev = document.addEventListener.bind(document);
```

So instead of creating new functions that wrap the original, you can alias the actual function itself.

You should do the same for your other aliases if you want to go with this approach.

```
const qs = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const qa = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

My final word of advise would be to not alias these methods at all. The abbreviated method names hurt the readability of your code. Readability almost always trumps brevity as it comes to code.

Comment: All these shorthands will throw if you just call them. And `qa.call(document, ...)` feels kind of clunky

Comment: Oopsie... Fixed it with bind.

Comment: May I know what's the difference between `const ev = document.addEventListener` and `const env = document.addEventListener.bind(document)`?

Comment: @KexinLi The second binds `this` to `document`. See [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @KexinLi also; don't do this. Any code on this page is basically a bad idea.

Comment: Does it means everytime we want to set a function to another variable, we should bind this for that function?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the previous answers as an inspiration and created my take on it.

### Core

```js
const $ = (selector, base = document) => {
  return base.querySelector(selector);
};

Node.prototype.on = function(type, listener) {
  return this.addEventListener(type, listener);
};
```

- It supports a base value in case you have another element than `document` but it's optional.
- I like `$` and `on` so that's what I use, just like jQuery.

### Call it like below

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```